# what really happens when we are using observer in rxjava?

Tags: java, android, rx-java, system.reactive, rx-android

I like to know what is really going on internally while we use a observer in RxJava, and how do the subscriber get all the data stream from the observer.

Thanking you all in advance.

Comment: What do you mean? The `onXXX` methods are called on those observers immediately or over time depending on the business- and operator logic.

Comment: random tip, in Android Studio if you click on a class or method while pressing ctrl it will jump to the source

Comment: The subscriber is the observer. It's the observable that produces the values. The observer consumes them.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of RxJava as an extreme generalization of the [Observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). You essentially register a call-back with the thing you are observing (the observable). The observable item calls `onNext()` whenever it has an item it wants to emit, then `onComplete()` when it is done.

All of the rest of the RxJava implementation supports flow control, composition of call-backs, allowing multiple call-backs on an observable, time-distortions, combining different observables, and thread management.

If you really want to know the internals, you can read the code. More importantly, you can read the narratives of David Karnok, a principal architect and developer of RxJava and reactive streams. Here is a [sample blog](http://akarnokd.blogspot.ca/2015/10/connectableobservables-part-1.html) describing internals of connected observables.